# How to run multiple query in find method mongoose?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've a controller and i'm querying into find method like:

```
Campaign.find({'setting.types':'views','ownerId':{$ne:userId},$where:"this.expected_views>this.views.length"}).exec().then(doc=>{
    res.status(200).json({
        'message':doc
    })
})
```

My database is like:

```
{
        "setting": {
            "bill": "900",
            "dateTime": "23-3-2020",
            "expected_time": "30",
            "expected_views": "30",
            "types": "views"
        },
        "views": [
            {
                "5678908ygvhjkhgg": true
            },
            {
                "hjsgsss687sHJSjhs": true
            }
        ],
        "_id": "609b7260e798aa14f8b6b2be",
        "id": "609b7260e798aa14f8b6b2bd",
        "imageUrl": "file.jpg",
        "link": "link",
        "ownerId": "dakdjdakdadmnkdsa"
    }
```

After querying using my controller the response it's sending `message=[]` what is wrong I'm doing?

my `$where:"this.expected_views>this.views.length"` clause in not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From MongoDB 4.4, [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#-where) no longer supports the deprecated BSON type JavaScript code with scope (BSON type 15). The `$where` operator only supports BSON type String (BSON type 2) or BSON type JavaScript (BSON type 13). The use of BSON type JavaScript with scope for `$where` has been deprecated since MongoDB 4.2.1.

I would recommend you to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), Starting in MongoDB 3.6, the `$expr` operator allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.

- use `$expr` condition and `$gt` operator and `$size` to get size of array
- `$toInt` convert `expected_views` from string to integer

```
Campaign.find({
  $and: [
    {
      "setting.types": "views",
      "ownerId": { $ne: userId }
    },
    {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [{ $toInt: "$setting.expected_views" }, { $size: "$views" }]
      }
    }
  ]
}).exec().then(doc => {
  res.status(200).json({ 'message': doc });
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8rtMKrqMlTo)

Comment: Wow turivishal you're awesome, well explained sir, can you explain little use of $and?

Comment: performs a logical AND operation on an array of one or more expressions/conditions and selects the documents that satisfy all the expressions in the array.

Comment: when my "expected_views" is less than the size of array "views" still it's responding?? according to the condition it should not show..

Comment: because `expected_views` is string it requires to convert in integer, check updated answer.

Comment: Superb turivishal. Thanks